# What is the switch for second monitor only

Tags: windows, command-line, multiple-monitors

When you press <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Windows 10 you will get this menu on the right side of the monitor:

[image]

The program and switches behind these options are as follows:

```
PC screen only :: displayswitch.exe /internal
Duplicate      :: displayswitch.exe /clone
Extend         :: displayswitch.exe /extend
```

What is the switch for:

```
Second screen only :: ???
```

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-does-displayswitchexe-work-in-windows-7/1d30ef62-881a-4a69-ac02-e496b1f794ef

Comment: Annnnnd nice to see `/help` does nothing. Sigh :( Good one MS!

Comment: While it's already answered, was it too hard to guess for /external after all /internal gives you only the internal monitor?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Second Screen only:

```
displayswitch.exe /external
```

This should hopefully help you with your problem.

Comment: is this displayswitch.exe windows 10 only ?

Comment: this works with windows 7 too.

Comment: you don't need to type the '.exe'