# Is it possible to switch displays when the ones in use are off?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

I've got 3 displays connected to my R7 250X, one of them being a TV 3m from my PC table where I have the other 2 monitors. I've installed a power switch, then hooked it up to the power cables of those monitors and I would like to know if there's a software way to make the OS change the active displays automatically from the monitors to the TV when I switch the monitors off, so I don't have to use windows+P which is buggy in win10 (after switching display it stays in the screen and I need to use a mouse to take it off, which I'm not using (it's mostly for steam so I only have a controller).

As of now, when I simply switch off the monitors (while having the TV plugged in), windows won't change to the TV and it just stays screenless, which is pretty stupid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what options do you get under Windows+P? you maybe able to  create .bat files running the commands found in here: https://superuser.com/questions/1211944/what-is-the-switch-for-second-monitor-only/1211951

Comment: I've done that actually, but what I'd like is to make it work automatically after I switch off the main monitors (if possible at least).

Under win+p i have the following settings:

Second screen only = monitors

PC screen only = HDMI TV